# How do I define a variable in Anylogic that show the value of another variable in yesterday?

Tags: variables, events, anylogic

Available variable count the number of walking in a day by statechart.
The new variable that I need to define is the number of walking in yesterday.

---

Now, I have two variables *dailyTravelByWalk* that it get its value from my statechart and *yesterdayTravelByWalk* that it get its value from the yesterday value of *dailyTravelByWalk* by a event. In addition, I have another variable (Id) that it is equal with *dailyTravelByWalk / yesterdayTravelByWalk*.
When I run the model, NaN error appear. If I remove Id, I do not have NaN error.[please click this pic link, yesterdayTravelByWalk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aU66Z.png)

[please click this pic link, Id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2Sdo.png)

You think what is the problem?
thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If it is really just about yesterday, create 2 variables `endOfToday` and `endOfYesterday`.

At the end of the day (or when your statechart triggers), you call:

```
endOfYesterday  = endOfToday;
endOfToday = newValueFromToday;
```

If you need to store all values, you can use a DataSet and add an entry each day.